# Node AWS lambda with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I've written a lambda to perform simple steps to a redshift database. It runs multiple queries with transaction. I use pg-promise.

```
'use strict';
const config = require('./redshift_config_from_env');
const redshiftConn = `pg://${config.user}:${config.password}@${config.host}/${config.database}`;
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

var tableCopyQuery = function(tableName) {
  return `
      ALTER TABLE ${tableName}_temp
      RENAME TO ${tableName}_process;
      CREATE TABLE ${tableName}_temp (LIKE ${tableName}_process);`;
};
var insertQuery = function(tableName) {
  return `
      INSERT INTO ${tableName}
      SELECT DISTINCT ${tableName}_process.*
        FROM ${tableName}_process
        LEFT JOIN ${tableName} USING (id)
       WHERE ${tableName}.id IS NULL
       ORDER BY ${tableName}_process.id;
      DROP TABLE ${tableName}_process;`;
};

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const client = pgp(redshiftConn);

  client.tx(function (t) {
    return t.batch([
      t.none(tableCopyQuery('active_connections')),
      t.none(insertQuery('active_connections')),
      t.none(tableCopyQuery('active_downloads')),
      t.none(insertQuery('active_downloads'))
    ]);
  })
    .then(function () {
      context.succeed(`Successfully Refreshed.`);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      context.fail(`Failed to run queries : ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    });
};
```

I think I may move sql queries into `.sql` file outside of the function.

Maybe the `var` could be turned into `let` because the scope will fit?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create the database object on every function call. Read [this answer (and its question) for an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427278/1575353).